# Intent.ACTION_CALL starts a skype call instead a "normal" phone call

Tags: android, android-intent

I have the folowing code and im starting it from a dialog fragment button:

```
 uri = "tel:"+ServerDialogCallUs.this.contents.getString("phone_number");
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
 intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
```

Instead of making a normal phone call this code starts a skype call. How can I give the user the option to chose between the normal call and a skype call.
Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

actually, i was missing the permission:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

after adding this permission to the manifest I can chose between a normal and a skype call.
Thanks

Comment: funny that the permission is not actually on the use of action_call, but rather on the use of the actual application, therefore allowing to make a skype call but not a regular call.

Comment: After adding this I am allow to choose the default action, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try to call setPackage() method, works fine:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setPackage("com.android.phone");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
startActitivy(intent);
```

Comment: "How can I give the user the option to chose between the normal call and a skype call."  This solution would not give the user that option, would it?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue and tried some answers:

1. Intent.ACTION_CALL will call, which needs probably the right permission, BUT using Intent.ACTION_DIAL and use an Intent Chooser, I got the right behaviour.
2. Regarding USSD like "*123*03#" which pops up also as question in this context, where android says, it cannot handle the intent

2.1. Uri.encode("#") is not the solution, it just adds a "23" to the phone numer

2.2. Skype handles the number wrong, it adds the country-code like +001. So Skype does not handle USSDs correctly. But it seems, I have no chance, to exclude this.

So, I did:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.fromParts("tel", "123456", null));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""), REQUEST_CODE));
```

From my point of view

```
intent.setPackage("com.android.phone");
```

is device dependent or at least does not leave "phone" included on my device.

Answer (score 0):

That's because

1. There is only skype installed as a phone call handler or
2. You associated skype as default handler for phone calls.

In the latter case, go to settings, apps, skype, and remove that association on the bottom of the app details screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your phone probably has Skype as the default app to handle the `Intent.ACTION_CALL`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
uri = "tel:"+ServerDialogCallUs.this.contents.getString("phone_number");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Call Using..."));
```